# Unterschied zwischen Abweisen und Ablehnen

Tags: difference

**Gerne würde ich würde den Unterschied zwischen diesen beiden Verben wissen.** Ich habe eine deutsche Serie angesehen, da hat man gesagt: "Du liebst aber abgewiesen sein" (von jemandem bezüglich romantischen Beziehungen). Da habe ich mich gefragt, ob man auch "abgelehnt werden" verwenden könnte.

Neben diesem Beispiel kann ich auch andere Beispiele gebrauchen. Indem ich mehrere Zusammenhänge sehe, denke ich, den Unterschied einfacher begreifen zu können.

Answer (score 1):

Beide Verben sind sehr ähnlich. **Eine einfache Regel, die oft passt: Personen weist man ab, Dinge oder Angebote lehnt man ab.** Daher würde ich in dem Kontext auch nicht abgelehnt statt abgewiesen verwenden.

Beispiele:

- Das Geschäft lehnt Kartenzahlung unter 10€ ab.
- Er weist ihre Annäherungsversuche ab.
- Die Verbraucher lehnen eine Preiserhöhung ab.

Es gibt aber auch Ausnahmen, wo es keine Person ist, aber trotzdem Abweisen verwendet wird.

Zum Beispiel:

- Das Gericht weist die Klage ab.

Comment: Manche Dinge (Bewerbungen, Anträge) können abgewiesen **und** abgelehnt werden. In dem Fall bedeutet *abweisen*, dass gar nicht darüber entschieden wird (zum Beispiel, weil der Antrag nicht fristgerecht gestellt wurde), während *ablehnen* bedeutet, dass eine negative Entscheidung getroffen wurde.

Answer (score 0):

Der von @PasWei erwähnte Unterschied, "der oft paßt", der paßt tatsächlich manchmal, aber oft genug auch nicht.

"Abweisen" setzt eine Bemühung des abgewiesenen voraus, *angenommen* zu werden. Das ist etwa im Falle des zweiten, von @PasWei erwähnten Beispiels der Fall:

> Er weist ihre Annäherungsversuche ab.

Diese Abweisung setzt aber die *Annäherungsversuche* voraus. Hingegen etwa:

> Er lehnt Annäherungsversuche ab.

Das bedeutet, daß *er* Annäherungsversuche generell - also zB. als Mittel zur Beziehungsanbahnung - ablehnt, womit die zuvor beschriebene *Bemühung* wegfällt. *Abgelehnt* wird nicht ein konkreter Annäherungsversuch, sondern das Konzept derselben. Hingegen:

> Er weist Annäherungsversuche ab.

Hier betrifft die Tätigkeit - die *Abweisung* - etwas, das zuvor unternommen werden mußte, nämlich die Annäherungsversuche.

Dementsprechend, und hier unterscheidet sich meine Definition von der der @PasWeis, können auch Nicht-Personen *abgewiesen* werden, sofern sie vorher eine Bemühung angenommen zu werden unternommen haben. Erwähnt wurde bereits die Klage bei Gericht (hier besteht die unternommene Anstrengung darin, daß die Klage *eingereicht* wurde).

Auch kann zB. ein Online-Bezahlterminal meine Kreditkarte *abweisen*, weil diese (stellvertretend für mich, ihren Besitzer) vorher den Versuch unternommen hat, angenommen zu werden. Das Bezahlen mittels dieser Karte - dies stellt keine eigene Bemühung dar - wird dann folgerichtig *abgelehnt*.